Nuxt 3 SSR user IP
how to transfer the client IP with SSR to the backend? Now I am transmitting the IP of the server on which the project is located
Global fetch configuration
import { ofetch } from 'ofetch';
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  const headers = useRequestHeaders(['cookie']);
  globalThis.$fetch = ofetch.create({
    headers,
    credentials: 'include',
    retry: 0,
  });
});

Plugin for initializing a user session and obtaining his geo
geo.ts
import { useGeoStore } from '~/store/geo';


export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
  const geoStore = useGeoStore();

  const { data: geo } = await useFetch('/api/v1/session', {
    baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().public.API_BASE_URL,
    headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
    watch: false
  });
});

Made a proxy layer for api requests
server/api/[...].ts
import { joinURL } from 'ufo';
import { defineEventHandler } from 'h3';

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  return proxyRequest(event, joinURL(config.public.API_BASE_URL, event.path));
});

if I rename geo.ts and geo.client.ts then everything works correctly and the IP is transferred to the user

What is your question here? if it works by changing the file name why not using that? if you need client ip address you can get it from request on server side.

The fact of the matter is that I don’t need to rename the file, since when initializing the project with SSR, I need to get the session id and data about the user’s geo, so that I can then use this in other requests. Now the IP of the server on which the project is running is sent to my server, not the user’s IP

I tried to overwrite the user's IP via H3, but I get the server IP
